# JS not executing onsubmit with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using a function called validateForm() to check forms before they're submitted.  The basic form is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
        {
        var fname=document.forms["reg"]["firstname"].value;
        var lname=document.forms["reg"]["lastname"].value;
        if (fname==null || fname=="Jane" ||fname=="" || lname==null || lname=="" || lname="Doe")
          {
          alert("You must provide your name");
          return false;
          }
</script>
```

Now, I have two registration pages.  One uses some simple HTML and CSS that I wrote myself and looks a million years old.  The other leverages Bootstrap because I'm taking baby steps to modernizing the look of the pages I maintain.  The plain HTML form has a structure like:

```
<form name="reg" action="include/registrationwriter.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="POST">
<strong>First Name*:</strong> <input type="TEXT" name="firstname" size="30" /><br />
<strong>Last Name*:</strong> <input type="TEXT" name="lastname" size="30" /><br />
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

While the bootstrap page has a structure like:

```
<div class="well">
    <form name="reg" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="tcqf_include/registrationwriter.asp" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Jane">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Doe">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disc"></span> Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, the plain HTML page, on submit does the appropriate check while the Bootstrap page ignores the check and goes straight to the ASP page that handles writing the results to the database.  Why does one work and the other does not?

Comment: normally action is executed before onsubmit. You can validate things but your data will be posted in any case. So use Ajax to post your data not action.

Comment: Don't listen to @PashaB, action is not *executed* at all. Shouldn't your `validateForm` function return `true` on success though?

Comment: Also, you have an error in `|| lname="Doe"`. Should be `==`

Comment: @Phil That's a great question - I guess it's been working for years without ever returning a true.  Regardless though, it's not returning `false` like it should.

Comment: @PashaB That's not the behavior I've experienced with my basic HTML - unless the function fails to pass a `false` no data is passed along.

Comment: @Mark Doesn't appear to be a problem other than the one mentioned above. See http://jsfiddle.net/L7ebw0hy/

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much for the Fiddle.  I've run into a strange issue.  I have three sets of radio buttons which I'm interested in ensuring have a selection.  I wrote a for loop to see if any value is selected for one of the radio button groups.  When I add a second one in the exact same way - it craps out on me. Do you have any idea what might be causing that? http://jsfiddle.net/L7ebw0hy/2/